# Google Analytics Custom Campaign returning user attribution

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

My question is regarding custom campaigns and how returning users are attributed when returning via a different source or medium.

I currently have a campaign set up where users are given the link (which was made using the URL builder). This is currently working perfectly in my campaign reports however I was wondering if a user is to return to my site at a later date via google, direct, referral, etc. (something different than the newsletter) will their new session still be attributed to the campaign?

I've done some testing and so far the user hasn't been attributed to the campaign. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone visits from your campaign with the utm parameters (made using the URL Builder), and then returns from a google search, a referral, another campaign with utm parameters, and so on, then the new visit will be attributed to the new traffic source, not the original campaign. If they visit directly, chances are it will be attributed to the previous traffic source. You can find all of the details in this flow chart: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/campaign-flow

If you want to see subsequent visits from someone who visited from a given campaign, I'd suggest using either Segmentation or Multi Channel funnels. With Segmentation, you can create a user based segment to see all visits from a user who satisfies some criteria: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en. With Multi Channel Funnels, you can see all of the traffic sources that lead to a conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 

If I was to use segmentation, do you have any advice as to how the segment should be created? I was thinking of creating a segment based on the region I'm looking to track and then either date of first session or campaign, however if the user returns via anything but a direct source, would they then not fall into that segment? 

I guess what I'm getting at is if their is a way to create a segment that will recognize users who initially came to the site via those utm parameters, even if they return via another source (other than direct)